# How can I get the data of this user by clicking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to click on the user from the list of users, on the right to display more information about it. Now displays a random user. Do I need to get its index and compare them? Help to understand and find the right information that will help to understand this

```
        {this.props.testStore.map((arrayItem, index) =>
              <Grid >
                  <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={6} computer={5}>
                      <Image src={randomUser.general.avatar} />
                  </Grid.Column>
                  <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={10} computer={11}>
                      <h2>{`${randomUser.general.firstName} ${randomUser.general.lastName}`}</h2>
                      <h3>Company: {randomUser.job.company}</h3>
                      <h3>Position: {randomUser.job.title}</h3>
                      <h4>
                          Contact:
                          <p><Icon name='mail' size='small' /> <a href="mailto:Gerry_Hackett77@gmail.com">{randomUser.contact.email}</a></p>
                          <p><Icon name='phone'  size='small' /> <a href="tel:8959840132">{randomUser.contact.phone}</a></p>
                      </h4>
                      <p><strong>Address:</strong> {`${randomUser.address.street}, ${randomUser.address.city}, ${randomUser.address.country}`}</p>
                  </Grid.Column>
              </Grid>
          )}
```

**array with users `testStore`**

```
const randomUser = this.props.testStore[8];
```

Here is my example code more detailed -> [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7oxkkpqoj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `index` (or user `id` if you have any) to `this.handleClick`.
Then inside the handler you can set it:

```
  handleClick(selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex });
  }
```

And then in your render:

```
  render() {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;
    const randomUser = this.props.testStore[selectedIndex];
...
```

But don't forget to have an initial value in the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0,
      show: true
    };
    this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arrayItem on your handleClick function

```
onClick={() => {
  this.handleClick(arrayItem);
  this.toggleAside();
}}
```

then setState with this item on handleClick

```
handleClick = arrayItem => {
  this.setState({ selected: arrayItem });
};
```

and then get the selected user from state on your render method and display the information you want.

```
const randomUser = this.state.selected;
```

and display only this user

```
{randomUser &&
  // code to display here
}
```